# Combine two .join methods into one

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Now I have this :

```
str = "  s  tr & &^ 23G7/*%45afju657**(%^#%$!!fdf"

str = ''.join(e for e in str if e.isalnum())
str = ''.join(('...', str, '...'))
```

Can I combine them like :

```
str = ''.join(('...', e for e in str if e.isalnum(), '...'))
```

Comment: Did you try running it?

Comment: No, because the `e for e...` part is not a string, which `join` needs. You could do something like: `str = ''.join(('...', ''.join(e for e in str if e.isalnum()), '...'))`

Comment: @SterlingArcher, http://ideone.com/QWJWmA

Comment: `str` for a variable name is not a good idea. It is a built-in (thanks @JoranBeasley) in Python

Comment: @fixxxer builtin ... not quite the same but plenty close for all intents and purposes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) there

```
s = "...{}...".format(''.join(e for e in s if e.isalnum()))
```

As a side note, do not name your string as `str` as it shadows the builtin

Apart from that, if you really really want to use `join` twice, you can write it as

```
''.join(('...', ''.join(e for e in s if e.isalnum()), '...'))
```

But it is not a good idea.  <sub>Why use a nuclear bomb to kill a mosquito!</sub>

Comment: oh lol I though `...` was other parts of his `my_str` ... not a litteral `...` +1

Comment: yeah 20-20 hindsight and re-reading the question I can see that :P

Comment: You use a nuke to kill a mosquito because there might be others near it and all mosquitos are evil and should burn.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Think of the environment too! :P

Comment: Thanks for you solution. If i want to use him with unicode like : `s = (u"...{}...".format(''.join(e for e in s.decode('utf-8') if e.isalnum()))).encode('utf-8')`  Is it proper? This works but I want to know your opinion.

Comment: Yes it is correct. A small tip - Upgrade to Python3, where you will not need to do all this encoding stuff. Have a @niceday !

Comment: @JoranBeasley I was going to say that it *isn't* a literal `...` but a literal `'...'`. But then I saw he's not using Python 3. Meh.

Answer (score 3):

you could do

```
my_str = ''.join(['...']+ [e for e in my_str if e.isalnum()] +['...'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just use the `+` operator? And `filter` is also quite nice. Since you use Python 2.7, you don't even need to re-join:

```
>>> s = "  s  tr & &^ 23G7/*%45afju657**(%^#%$!!fdf"
>>> s = '...' + filter(str.isalnum, s) + '...'
>>> s
'...str23G745afju657fdf...'
```

Comment: I like the use of `str.` here. For longer strings in 2.7, would it be faster to use `join()` instead of concatenation?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Instead of what concatenation? Oh you mean the `+`? I don't think so, but I'll try.

Comment: No, made no difference. Why would it?

Comment: Is `+` concatenation not slow (i.e., evaluating the whole string with each concatenation) in 2.7?

Comment: I assume you mean something like `for _ in range(1000000): s='a'+s`? That has nothing to do with what I do here.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Oops, forgot to tag you when I answered.

Answer (score 2):

```
string = "  s  tr & &^ 23G7/*%45afju657**(%^#%$!!fdf"
```

You can use [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#filter) as syntactic sugar for a comprehension. It works best for functions rather than methods, however - the `lambda` that disguises the string method as a function makes this slow compared to the simple comprehension (thanks, @Bhargav).

```
string = ''.join(['...', ''.join(filter(lambda x: x.isalnum(), string)), '...'])
```

or:

```
string = ''.join(filter(lambda x: x.isalnum(), string)).join(['...']*2)
```

depending on what ordering you prefer.

Comment: It is interesting to note that the use of `lambda` here makes the operation terribly slow compared to non-lambda solutions which are all almost at the same speed.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 small typo, need x.isalnum()

Comment: Lambda slowness noted, error fixed. Thanks for pointing those out.

Comment: @BhargavRao How "terribly slow" is it, and what are those faster solutions? TigerhawkT3: Why do you create that lambda in the first place? (see my answer)

Comment: @StefanPochmann Why don't you use the `timeit` module and try it for yourself! (Your answer may be the winner actually)

Comment: @BhargavRao I asked because I had already done exactly that. With a 10 million characters string. My version took 2.8 seconds, comprehension took 3.9 seconds, and lambda took 4.5 seconds. That's not terribly slow, so I'm wondering whether you were just wrong or had some other solutions in mind.

Comment: @StefanPochmann The solution is 0.6 seconds slower by using `lambda` (u see lambda u see slow - remember this motto). And as I mentioned yours is clearly the winner! Nice answer there! :)